# Why am I unable to start a Python web server in Mavericks? All the .py files return as plain text

Tags: python, webserver

In the Terminal, I navigated to the folder I wanted and ran `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and then navigated to `0.0.0.0:8000` and saw the listing of my `.py` files. When I click on any of then, however, it just returns plain text. I'm using OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: It'll do the same on any OS, because `SimpleHTTPServer` serves plain files, not scripts.

Comment: How is that a server then?

Comment: It is a plain file server, not a CGI server. See the dupe.

Comment: The documentation for [the module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) explains what it does, and the fact that the immediately next thing in [the list of modules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/internet.html) is called "`CGIHTTPServer`: CGI-capable HTTP request handler" implies pretty strongly that the "Simple HTTP request handler" isn't CGI-capable.